# Truncating Normalised Distribution Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, normal-distribution

I have created normal distributions for a range of means and standard deviations. Each distribution needs to be returned to a column of a data frame.

```
dat
     mu  sigma
0   0.0  0.1
1   0.1  0.1
2   0.2  0.1
3   0.3  0.1
...
100 0.9  0.9 

N = 10000
new = pd.DataFrame()        
for index, row in dat.iterrows():
    q = np.random.normal(row['mu'], row['sigma'],N)
    new[index] = q
```

I need to truncate each distribution to a range of (0,1). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 0):

use `clip()` method:

```
  new =  new.clip(0,1)
```

if you want to replace with nan

```
import numpy as np
ts.clip(0,1).replace([0,1],np.nan)
```

Comment: I need the outliers to be NaN, is there an equally simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For performance and especially when dealing with numerical data, I would suggest working at array level. Here's one approach following that philosophy and using `masking` to assign new values -

```
arr = new.values
arr[(arr < 0 ) | (arr > 1)] = np.nan
```

Also, when we extract the values as array, we are making a view there. So, all the assigned values are directly assigned to the original dataframe.

Let's have a look at a sample run to make things clear -

```
In [98]: new
Out[98]: 
          0         1         2         3
0 -0.043621  0.130358  0.080129  0.328385
1  0.254040  0.182079  0.196277  0.200776
2 -0.095340  0.079365  0.087692  0.248947
3 -0.121635 -0.034989  0.234536  0.247606
4  0.156337  0.164760  0.202639  0.326892

In [99]: arr = new.values

In [100]: arr[(arr < 0 ) | (arr > 1)] = np.nan

In [101]: new
Out[101]: 
          0         1         2         3
0       NaN  0.130358  0.080129  0.328385
1  0.254040  0.182079  0.196277  0.200776
2       NaN  0.079365  0.087692  0.248947
3       NaN       NaN  0.234536  0.247606
4  0.156337  0.164760  0.202639  0.326892
```